# Combine Pandas DataFrames when using multiprocessing

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I am using multiprocessing, and generating a pandas DataFrame with each process. I would like to merge them together and output the data. The following strategy seems almost work, but when trying to read in the data with `df.read_csv()` it only uses the first `name` as a column header.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock

def foo(name, lock):
    d = {f'{name}': [1, 2]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

    lock.acquire()
    try:
        df.to_csv('output.txt', mode='a')
    finally:
        lock.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = Lock()

    for name in ['bob','steve']
        p = Process(target=foo, args=(name, lock))
        p.start()
    p.join()
```

Comment: Were you expecting the columns to be concatenated horizontally?  CSV files don't do that.  You might consider using a `multiprocessing.Queue` to pass your end result back to the originating process, and leave the master process in charge of combining things.

Comment: @TimRoberts that is a great solution, then i can just combine the dataframes and write out at the same time, makes sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `multiprocessing.Pool`:

```
import multiprocessing
import pandas as pd

def foo(name):
    d = {f'{name}': [1, 2]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
    return df

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = ['bob', 'steve']
    with multiprocessing.Pool(2) as pool:
        data = pool.map(foo, data)
    pd.concat(data, axis=1).to_csv('output.csv')
```

Output:

```
>>> pd.concat(data, axis=1)
   bob  steve
0    1      1
1    2      2
```