# multiprocessing and concat dataframe result

Tags: python, pandas, python-multiprocessing

I have a function `main_fun()` with 3 arguments. (And it returns the `pandas dataframe`)

i use the multiprocessing on this within for loop:

```
def main_fun(ar1, ar2, ar3):
    # Do something
    df = ar1.copy()
    return df


process_list = []
for i in glob.glob(FolderPath + "/*.csv"):
    for j in ['File1', 'File2']:
        if (j == 'File1'): j_tmp = 'File1_XXX'
        else: j_tmp = j
        if j_tmp in i.upper():
            p = mp.Process(target = main_fun, args = (i, j, FolderPath + '/This_Is_Fixed.csv'))
            p.start()
            process_list.append(p)
for process in process_list:
    process.join()
```

With above, I can get the job done.
However, if I want to collect each dataframe results and concat them after `multiprocessing`, how should I do with this for loop?

Comment: Your code is a bit confused. Maybe you should use `Pool` and `starmap` Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69682765/15239951) but replace `map` by `starmap` because your function takes more than one parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer with simple example:

```
def foo(name, name2):
    d = {'col1': f'{name}', 'col2': f'{name2}'}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=[d])
    return df

arg1 = []
arg2 = []
for i in ['bob1_XX', 'steve_XX', 'andy_XX']:
    for j in ["BOB", "ANDY"]:
        if (j == 'BOB'): j_tmp = 'BOB1'
        else: j_tmp = j
        if j_tmp in i.upper():
            arg1.append(i)
            arg2.append(j)

with mp.Pool(processes = (mp.cpu_count() - 1)) as pool:
    data = pool.starmap(foo, zip(arg1, arg2))
pd.concat(data, axis=0)
```